# Why does the Opera browser send many "MessageEvent" messages using Nextjs in the console?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, opera

I've been using firefox for programming all my life, but recently I decided to try Opera, since I found the browser very interesting, but I'm fed up with this insane spamming of the "MessageEvent" console, does anyone else have this problem? I'm using Nextjs 13

My console screen

[image]

I hope someone from the community like me who is experiencing this problem knows how to solve it :C

Answer (score 1):

Going into Opera Settings and searching cash back and turning it off should fix the issue.